# How to invite Facebook, twitter, gmail friends into organic groups

Tags: organic-groups, social-network

How can i invite Facebook, twitter,Gmail friends in to my Organic Groups in Drupal 6.
Is there any possibility about this. Let me know.
Thanks,
Thiru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [Contact Importer](http://drupal.org/project/contact_importer) module.

> Contact Importer provides a form for your users to enter their email
>   address and password. The contacts from their address book are then
>   retrieved.

Of course you need to alter the module to send invites.

Or

Try using [Rules Module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) with this, to make it a chained process.

Comment: set up contact importer problemsssssssss

Comment: Is there any guide tutorial to make this........

Comment: It is a Drupal best practice to read readme.txt http://drupalcode.org/project/contact_importer.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt

Comment: I have followed althose stuff from read.txt file. And i can not able to see webservices link in the flow: Administer » Configuration » Web Services » Contact Importer » Settings

Comment: Open the .module file and search for menu hook and find the link !!!

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind when using this module, your host may think you are transmitting spam and suspend your account. I found it better to create a Facebook App and a Twitter app and go that route. Very easy to do.